What’s the difference between Litvish and regular Ashkenazi?
I know Litvaks are a group of people who belong to the Ashkenazi nusach, but not all a
Ashkenazi, as far as I know, are considered
Litvaks. Perhaps there are more differences than just the place where they come from. What are the major differences, if there are any, between them to able to identify who’s Litvak and who’s not?
Thank you so much for your time.

Welcome to MY! Besides Litvaks, there are other groups among Ashkenazim, like German and Hungarian Jews. The former introduced to their rite many mystical teachings of their most eminent figure, the Vilna Gaon, while the latter decided to keep kabbalistic practices in private for a small group of leading scholars, like the Chatam Sofer.

I think the confusion on the part of some, stems from the fact that socio-culturally the term "Litvish" is often used today interchangeably with Ashkenazi-Yeshivish, even to refer to Ashkenazim of non-Litvish ancestry. This is probably due to the fact that starting in the 19th century, the Lithuanian yeshivah model has come to dominate Orthodoxy. So whether one intends by the term someone of Jewish-Lithuanian ancestry or whether they merely intend a person culturally at home in the Ashkenazi-Yeshivah world, will depend on context.

Ashkenazim lived in the Rhineland (France/Germany), other parts of Germany, Holy Roman Empire, and Poland/Lithuania.
The Rhineland was mostly destroyed in the crusades, the rest of Germany tended to go towards the Reform movement during the enlightenment. The remaining Orthodox German Jews are called Yekkies. To the east, Jews from Poland towards Romania tended to follow the chassidic movement. The Jews of Lithuania founded most of the Yeshivas, and the Litvaks were the culture that was based on them.
When we say Litvaks today, we tend to mean a black hat Orthodox Jew whose traditions descend from the Lithuanian yeshivas and who isn't a Chassid.
The distinction is only relevant at a sophisticated level of religious observance. A cultural bagels-and-shmear Lower East Sider wouldn't be called a Litvak even if his ancestors came from Lithuania. You'd just call him an Ashkenazi Jew.

Chassisim are red. Litvaks are green.

A few details of Lithuanian nusach are sephardic in origin (for eample opening of the Torah ark). Many Lihuanian Jews were descenands of escapes from Spain.

"Ashkenazi" usually refers to Jews whose ancestry is European in origin, while Sefardi Jews' ancestry generally is Middle Eastern and North African in origin.
Among Ashkenazi Jews, there are Litvaks and Chassidim. The border between the two is sometimes a bit fuzzy, so exactly how you define each category depends on the person. However, nearly everyone would agree that the categories are mutually exclusive, meaning that a person cannot be both Litvish and Chassidish (although one can definitely consider themselves to be in neither category).
Which nusach one davens in is a different distinction. Chassidim will generally daven Nusach Sfard, while Litvaks are split between those who daven Nusach Ashkenaz and those who daven Nusach Sfard. Notice that "Nusach Sfard," while it sounds very much like the "Sefardi" mentioned in the first paragraph, isn't actually used by Sefardi Jews, but rather is "Sefardi" in origin. Sefardi Jews generally use the "Eidut HaMizrach" nusach for tefilla.

What self-respecting litvak would daven nusach sefard?

@JoelK I grew up with a bunch of such people. Although, on second thought, I'm not sure exactly how litvish they considered themselves, but they definitely didn't consider themselves chassidish, so...

If I had to guess, I would assume their background would not have been in Lita. They or their ancestors are likely to have come predominantly chassidic areas in Europe, but decided not to join the obviously chassidic communities in their new homes, quietly shedding many but not all of their chassidic practices.

"a person cannot be both Litvish and Chassidish" - this is a longtime misconception.  The Magid of Mezerich sent Aharon HaGadol of Karlin, Menachem Mendel of Vitebsk, and Shneur Zalman of Liadi to spread chassidus in Lita (the region of present-day Lithuania & Belarus).  From that effort emerged the Chassidic groups of Karlin-Stolin, Slonim, Kobrin, Koidanov, Chabad/Lubavitch and more.  So while Litvak culture was more famous for its misnagdim, there were plenty of Chassidim there.  In Mir there were chassidic groups and Zalman Shazar (president of Israel) grew up in a Chabad family there.

No, I went to a Litvish Yeshiva that was full of people who adored chassidus. The "boundary" between the two has been smashed in many communities and constantly playing up the "differences" with strong statements like "everyone would agree" and "mutually exclusive" isn't helping anything. -1
